# How to manage the boost::di injector?

Tags: c++, boost, dependency-injection

I don't seem to grasp the usefulness of using an [`injector`](https://boost-experimental.github.io/di/user_guide/index.html#injector) with [boost::di](https://boost-experimental.github.io/di/index.html).

I think I understand the power of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), and how its extensive usage leads to large number of arguments in classes' constructors.
I also see how the library helps managing the scope of dependencies and other things.

What I don't see, is that how this `injector` does not became a collection of input parameters for the used classes. I'm afraid that instead of passing all the singletons in the application to each object, I'm going to pass the fully configured `injector` object. It's true that it's a lot simpler than keeping track of *all* the singletons and other dependencies, but still, it seems that this approach just mitigates the problem instead of solving it, like it promises.

Is the `injector` just a fancy factory? Should I make my `injector` global to avoid this?

Dependency injection frameworks are fairly popular, so I must miss something.

Comment: You should not need a global injector, nor need to pass it around. Classes would take dependencies and `main` would register those dependencies and create one specific class object, which would cause the injector to create and pass in its dependencies, which keeps going as necessary.

Comment: @chris: and how do I manage my bindings for example? Do I set them in `main()` as well? What if they have to be defined at a lower level? E.g. the application uses objects with different bindings in each module.

Comment: Yes, binding are normally set in modules that are used from `main`. If that requires a later runtime decision (e.g., the user chooses a strategy), the dependency could be changed to an abstract factory. But with DI in general, the creation of complex classes (ones that have dependencies) is pushed to the composition root (`main`). You can certainly have Boost.DI modules that reflect actual modules and then combine them. I think what would help is going out and looking for a breadth of examples, with Java and C# being a good place to look, since this is more widespread there.

Comment: @chris, I think that your comments can be turned into an answer as well. If you could point me to the relevant examples, I'd be grateful. The [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#AngularJS_example) does not solve the problem, instead uses an AngularJS-specific "workaround".